# Hacer que el circle de Google Maps no afecte a un click sobre el mapa

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Tengo un mapa de Google en el que puedo poner un marcador, arrastrarlo y con él va un círculo que es el radio de búsqueda.

Mi problema es que si hago click dentro del radio no me llama al evento que hace mover el marcador hasta la posición del puntero, ya que el radio está por encima.

¿Qué puedo hacer para que el círculo se vea pero no le afecten los clicks?

```
var pos = {
    lat: latitud,
    lng: longitud
};
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    center: pos,
    zoom: 6
});
marcador = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    draggable: true,
    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
});
marcador.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
centerMarkerMap();
circulo = new google.maps.Circle({
    strokeColor: '#44a373',
    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
    strokeWeight: 1,
    fillColor: '#44a373',
    fillOpacity: 0.25,
    map: map
});
circulo.setRadius(parseInt(inpRadius.value) * 1000);
circulo.bindTo('center', marcador, 'position');

//Evento del mapa que crea los marcadores al hacer click    
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
    marcador.setMap(null);
    circulo.setMap(null);
    marcador = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        position: event.latLng,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    marcador.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
    estandarizarPos(event.latLng);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marcador, 'dragend', function () {
        estandarizarPos(marcador.getPosition());
    });
    circulo = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: '#44a373',
        strokeOpacity: 0.5,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: '#44a373',
        fillOpacity: 0.25,
        map: map
    });
    circulo.setRadius(parseInt(inpRadius.value) * 1000);
    circulo.bindTo('center', marcador, 'position');
});
google.maps.event.addListener(marcador, 'dragend', function () {
    estandarizarPos(marcador.getPosition());
});
```

Comment: Carlos Bienvenido a SO en español, podrias agregar el codigo que utilizas para que podamos ayudarte mas, ya que actualmente no te podemos ayudar mucho

Comment: Carlos, necesitamos que nos muestres el código que crea el marcador, el manejo del arrastre y la forma en que agregas el circulo, es esencial para saber como evitar que el circulo se quede con los eventos.

Comment: Lo siento. Ya he puesto el código.

Comment: Olvida mi comentario anterior. Ya puedo ver el círculo: estaba poniendo un valor demasiado bajo en inpRadius.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Una posible solución no es evitar que al círculo le afecten los clicks, sino todo lo contrario: que escuche los clicks y que ejecute una acción cuando ocurran (en concreto la misma acción que ocurriría cuando se pulsa sobre otro punto del mapa).

Esto se puede conseguir en dos simples pasos:

- Saca la función anónima que hay en el controlador del evento `click` del mapa y dale un nombre (por ejemplo, `mapaPulsado`)
- Añade un controlador del evento `click` en el círculo apuntando a la función que acabas de crear en el paso anterior.

Lo he probado y funciona bien (el mapa se centra en el lugar que pulses dentro del círculo). Ésta sería la parte del código que cambiaría:

```
//Evento del mapa que crea los marcadores al hacer click    
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (event) {
    marcador.setMap(null);
    circulo.setMap(null);
    marcador = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        position: event.latLng,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    marcador.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
    estandarizarPos(event.latLng);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marcador, 'dragend', function () {
        estandarizarPos(marcador.getPosition());
    });
    circulo = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: '#44a373',
        strokeOpacity: 0.5,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: '#44a373',
        fillOpacity: 0.25,
        map: map
    });
    circulo.setRadius(parseInt(inpRadius.value) * 1000);
    circulo.bindTo('center', marcador, 'position');
});
```

Que pasaría a ser así:

```
//Evento del mapa que crea los marcadores al hacer click    
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', mapaPulsado);

// función que se llama cuando se pulsa en el mapa o en el círculo
function mapaPulsado(event) {
    marcador.setMap(null);
    circulo.setMap(null);
    marcador = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        position: event.latLng,
        animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
    });
    marcador.addListener('click', toggleBounce);
    estandarizarPos(event.latLng);
    google.maps.event.addListener(marcador, 'dragend', function () {
        estandarizarPos(marcador.getPosition());
    });
    circulo = new google.maps.Circle({
        strokeColor: '#44a373',
        strokeOpacity: 0.5,
        strokeWeight: 1,
        fillColor: '#44a373',
        fillOpacity: 0.25,
        map: map
    });
    circulo.setRadius(parseInt(inpRadius.value) * 1000);
    circulo.bindTo('center', marcador, 'position');

    // añadimos el controlado del click para el círculo
    circulo.addListener("click", mapaPulsado);
}
```

Comment: Gracias por tu rápida respuesta ;)